# Prototype based function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I just interviewed at a company where they asked me to implement something like  `xyz.odd()`.

It should be like this:

```
let arr=[1,2,1,2];
arr=arr.odd();// this array will contain all odd numbers [1,1]
```

I tried, but ended up writing a function where I passed the array but that was not expected.I was not asked to pass any values or array in function.

Comment: look into prototype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes , You did mention prototype based function so what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the code below to create a prototype method that will be available to all instances of `Array`:

```js
Array.prototype.odd = function() {
  return this.filter(el => el % 2 === 1);
}

//Examples:
var arr = [1, 2, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(arr.odd());
console.log(arr2.odd());
```

Comment: Although if this is done during a job interview, perhaps the interviewer is testing to see if the interviewee knows that it is considered bad practice to extend native objects.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree with you 100% and I wouldn't extend native objects in my own code. However, I provided this answer because, based on OP, it seems (to me) to be what the interviewer wanted to see.